# Exchange 2016 - delete all items on specific mailbox older than x years

Tags: exchange-2016

I can't find a definite answer how to achieve this.
I have a huge mailbox (over 150GB) than I want to delete anything older than Apr 2018.
How can I do this in exchange 2016 (I can't use outlook as the items are on the exchange mailbox and you can't search/see them in outlook due to the size of the mailbox)

Answer (score 0):

Provided that you are an Exchange administrator, you can create a new retention policy using some retention tags that re intended for deleting items older than Apr 2018, then apply the retention policy to the specific mailbox, run Start-ManagedFolderAssistant against the mailbox to manually run the MRM assistant.

Detailed instructions, you can follow the steps in the official document below:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/policy-and-compliance/mrm/create-retention-policies?view=exchserver-2016

Another option is to use the Search-Mailbox cmdlet(Requires Mailbox Search or Mailbox Import Export role) similar like below:

```
Search-Mailbox -Identity <UserIdentity> -SearchQuery '(kind:email OR kind:meetings) AND (received<04/01/2018)' -DeleteContent
```

Reference: https://www.codetwo.com/admins-blog/how-to-delete-email-from-mailboxes-on-exchange-2016-2013-2010-online/